# Calling a mysql procedure using pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have a procedure called'my' in mysql. The query is as below

```
CREATE DEFINER=`as`@`%` PROCEDURE `my`()
BEGIN
    delete from my1 where datediff(curdate(), Date_) <= 20;
    insert into my1
            select
                t.idx auto_increment,
                t.date_ as 'Date_',
                t.brand as 'Br',
                concat(t.so_, '_', t.me_) as 'Md'
                from 
                    (select idx, date_, brand, so_, me from md where datediff(curdate(), Date_) <= 20) as t
                group by t.date_, t.br;
END
```

To run this procedure in Python, I wrote the following code using pymysql.

```
user = 'xxxx'
passw = 'xxxxx'
host = 'xxxx'
port = 3306
database = 'DBxxxx'
conn = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                       port=port,
                       user=user,
                       password=passw,
                       database=database,
                       charset='utf8',
                       local_infile=1)
    try:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
              cursor.callproc('my')
              conn.commit()
              conn.close()
    except:
        conn.close()
```

But it doesn't work well. Are there any mistakes in the code I wrote? The procedure I run in mysql works fine

Comment: `delete from my1 where datediff(curdate(), Date_) <= 20;` - Try not to use a column in the expression, this decreases the performance, use condition form like `delete from my1 where Date_ >= curdate() - interval 20 day;` (use "clear", non-changed column value). In this case the expression `curdate() - interval 20 day` is a constant, it is evaluated once, and the index by `Date_` may be used (if exists). Rather then in your query.

Comment: Was the part where I wrote ```pymysql```  right?

Comment: I do not use python...